# MySQL sort order by both timestamp and enum

Tags: mysql, enums, timestamp, sql-order-by

I'm trying to sort order by both timestamp and enum (main order timestamp, "sub-order" enum), but it seems only one or the other works.

It's a very simple table called `table`:

`id | task | date_estimated [timestamp] | status [enum]`

I've tried:

`select * from table order by date_estimated DESC, status DESC`

which, should, in theory, give me something that is sub-sorted by enum status per date, right?

```
3/5/2012
added - gas up
done - buy milk
done - buy pencils
```

But, it's giving me a jumble like

```
3/5/2012
done - buy milk
added - gas up
done - buy pencils
```

How do I write a query to sort like the first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`select * from table order by DATE(date_estimated) DESC, status DESC`

The timestamp field includes hours/minutes/seconds so you'd get an odd order if you were looking for the actual date part considering the event would have to occur on the same second in order for the sub-group to make sense in your query.

Comment: The Date() was exactly what fixed it. Now they're first ordered by date, and then sub ordered by enums! This has been the solution after an hour of odd frustration. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. Just remember that when using multiple order bys your first order by condition will have to result in more than one value being duplicated in your result set in order for the second order by to kick in.

Answer (score 1):

Check this paragraph from the MySQL documentation:

> ENUM values are sorted according to the order in which the enumeration
>   members were listed in the column specification. (In other words, ENUM
>   values are sorted according to their index numbers.) For example, 'a'
>   sorts before 'b' for ENUM('a', 'b'), but 'b' sorts before 'a' for
>   ENUM('b', 'a'). The empty string sorts before nonempty strings, and
>   NULL values sort before all other enumeration values. To prevent
>   unexpected results, specify the ENUM list in alphabetic order. You can
>   also use ORDER BY CAST(col AS CHAR) or ORDER BY CONCAT(col) to make
>   sure that the column is sorted lexically rather than by index number.

Each enum value is mapped to a number (its index number) and that's the value that is used when sorting. That's why it's not sorted by the string representation in your results.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Comment: But, if it's sorted by enum integer, the "added" should be bunched with the added and the "done" with the done... instead it's just a mix of the two.